# Entity framework data missing

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have tables linked by FK, I query on the first table using entity framework.  I expected to be able to do the following

```
<table1>.<table2>
```

in .NET

Is this not the case?  How would I get the whole chain of tables available to me by querying on the first table?

Comment: You'll need to show some code.  You can definitely get at foreign key data via navigation properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fetch related items like;

```
myContext.A.Include("B");
```

In this case, all items for table A and all related items from table B are fetched.
Also you can use a typed version of Include function like;

```
mycontext.A.Include(p => p.B);
```

Comment: One side question if I can - are those chainable?  I.e. .Include("B").Include("C") where C has FK on B?

Comment: Yo may chain like; mycontext.A.Include("B.C")

Answer (score 4):

I think you're asking for [Eager Loading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738449.aspx).

```
context.Table1.Inclde("Table2").ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you sir - not sure who answered first, both say same time :)  Marking this one as answer.

Comment: @dbobrowski: daryal was about half a minute ahead of me. You can hover over the "x mins ago" to see the actual time that the question was answered, down to the second.